# How to use VLC as a DVR (split-screen)?

Tags: networking, video, vlc-media-player, streaming

Is there any way to make VLC tune into multiple sources/streams and display them as a single split screen?

My Main goal is to then take this single screen and multicast it on my office network.

If VLC cannot do this, is it possible to do with any other software?

To illustrate:

I have multiple multicast streams in an isolated network, I want to be able to create a single split screen stream (I don't care for audio) and multicast it out off of a different interface to my office network, worst case, I would want to unicast it to a particular address.

Comment: What OS are you on?  I don't think VLC will do this, but [here's a similar question from StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15391368/how-to-combine-multiple-ffmpeg-streams-into-a-single-4x4-collage) about using ffmpeg to do it.

Comment: Actually apparently what I want is called a mosaic, I found this tutorial: https://wiki.videolan.org/Mosaic/#VLC_mosaic_howto however this is not working (yet) for me, the command in step 4 is giving some problems